# makefile stopping after some commands in windows

Tags: windows, cordova, makefile

this is my first time using makefile to simplify my hybrid mobileapps developement. So, i have this pretty makefile which refuses to run after some commands. Please have a check.

```
.PHONY: run
OUTPUT_FILE=final.apk
ALIAS=mycert
KEYPASS=shittypass
KEYSTORE=certs/bang.keystore
UNSIGNED=platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk
PACKAGE='com.example.testapp'
sign:
    del -f ${OUTPUT_FILE}
    cordova build android --release
    jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ${KEYSTORE} -storepass ${KEYPASS} ${UNSIGNED} ${ALIAS}
    zipalign -v 4 ${UNSIGNED} ${OUTPUT_FILE}

execute:
    adb shell am start -n ${PACKAGE}/${PACKAGE}.MainActivity

install:
    adb install -r ${OUTPUT_FILE}

    log:
        adb logcat | grep `adb shell ps | grep ${PACKAGE} | cut -c10-15`

    run: sign install execute log
```

The commands under "sign:" section are running perfectly but log: execute: and install: are not even showing in the cmd.
I am using Windows 7 and GnuWin32 make program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make always tries to build only the first target in the makefile, unless you specify a specific target on the command line; for example you could invoke `make sign install execute log` and it would run them all.

It looks like you wanted the `run` target to be the default target when you type `make`; if so it must be the *first* target in the makefile not the last one.

Also, you should not be indenting the `log` and `run` targets like you do in your example above.  It's confusing at best and an error at worst.

Comment: Thanks, I shifted the run target before sign so it is the first target now and it works well now. any idea what's the .PHONY thing at top is all about?

Comment: Read about phony targets here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html